# Как вернуть callback из xhr?

Tags: ajax, callback, xhr

Как вернуть `callback` из `XHR` запроса?

В AJAX jQuery есть простая возможность нужного мне возврата:

```
window._request = function (url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url     : url,
        type    : 'POST',
        success : successCallback,
        error   : errorCallback
    });
}
```

Не пойму как сделать так, чтобы ответ `successCallback`, `errorCallback` работал в этой функции:

```
window._request = function (url, successCallback, errorCallback) {

        var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
        var xhr = new XHR();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            successCallback // ???????????????????????????????????????????????????
          };
        };

        xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    successCallback.call(this); //или просто successCallback(this)
} else {
    errorCallback.call(this); //или просто errorCallback(this)
}
```